# Securing custom rest API endpoints with public access from PWA

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I'am trying to implement a headless woocommerce based PWA on ionic angular stack. I'am now accessing the woocommerce rest endpoints by using client id and secret. To make it more secure iam writing proxy custom endpoints in my custom plugin. But I need a way to secure this endpoints as some of them are publicly accessible by the PWA.
Can someone suggest best way to do this ?

Comment: what's the reasoning behind adding duplicated proxy custom endpoints? And by secure what do you mean? If an endpoint is public then it's public, what's the concern you have?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell . The duplicate proxy end points are for making sure the client secret and key are not exposed in the request. I also need to make sure the custom endpoint is only requested from my PWA only.

Comment: @TomJNowell Could you suggest a way to make the endpoint secure so that only my PWA app can access it even if it is public.

Comment: You're either going to have to embed some other secret in your app (which you can change with every release, and disable old ones) or ask your users to sign up for accounts and authenticate them that way. Or just accept that there's a public API to your site if someone is willing to dig through your code to find it.

Comment: if only your PWA can access it then it's not really public is it? Even then there's nothing stopping someone just opening the dev tools on the PWA and seeing what you did. This looks like a lot of effort for almost no gain at all, the only real answer is that if you don't want data to be public don't make it public. I strongly advise against your proxy endpoints, this is security theatre, and you're just increasing the attack surface area and weakening your security